# Regional API Gateway with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, regions

Amazon released [new feature - to support regional api endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-regional-api-endpoints/)

Does it mean I can deploy my same API code  in two regions which sends request to Lambda micro-services? (It will be two different Https endpoints)

And have CloudFront distribute the traffic for me?

Any code snippets?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Does it mean I can deploy my same API code in two regions which sends request to Lambda micro-services? (It will be two different Https endpoints)

This was already possible.  You can already deploy the same API code in multiple regions and create different HTTPS endpoints using API Gateway.

What you couldn't do, before, was configure API Gateway API endpoints in different regions to expect the same hostname -- and this is a critical capability that was previously unavailable, if you wanted to have a geo-routing or failover scenario using API Gateway.

With the previous setup -- which has now been renamed "Edge-Optimized Endpoints" -- every API Gateway API had a regional endpoint hostname but was automatically provisioned behind CloudFront.  Accessing your API from anywhere meant you were accessing it through the CloudFront, which meant optimized connections and transport from the API client -- anywhere on the globe -- back to your API's home region via the AWS Edge Network, which is the network that powers CloudFront, Route 53, and S3 Transfer Acceleration.

Overall, this was good, but in some cases, it can be better.

The new configuration offering, called a Regional API Endpoint, does not use CloudFront or the Edge Network... but your API is still only in one region (but keep reading).

Regional API Endpoints are advantageous in cases like these:

If your traffic is from EC2 within the region, this avoids the necessity of jumping onto the Edge Network and back off again, which will optimize performance of API requests from inside the same EC2 region.

If you wanted to deploy an API Gateway endpoint behind a CloudFront distribution that you control (for example, to avoid cross-origin complications, or otherwise integrate API Gateway into a larger site), this previously required that you point your CloudFront distribution to the CloudFront distribution managed by API Gateway, thus looping through CloudFront twice, which meant transport latency and some loss of flexibility.

Creating a Regional API Endpoint allows you to then point your own CloudFront distribution directly at the API endpoint.

If you have a single API in a single region, and it's being accessed from points all over the globe, and you aren't using CloudFront yourself, the Edge-Optimized endpoint is still almost certainly the best way to go.

But Regional API Endpoints get interesting when it comes to custom domain names.  Creating APIs with the same custom domain name (e.g. `api.example.com`) in multiple AWS regions was not previously possible, because of API Gateway's dependency on CloudFront.  CloudFront is a global service, so the hostname namespace is also global -- only one CloudFront distribution, worldwide, can respond to a specific incoming request hostname.  Since Regional API Endpoints don't depend on CloudFront, provisioning APIs with the same custom domain name in multiple AWS regions becomes possible.

So, assuming you wanted to serve `api.example.com` out of both us-east-2 and us-west-2, you'd deploy your individual APIs and then in each region, create a custom domain name configuration in each region for `api.example.com` with a Regional API Endpoint, selecting an ACM certificate for each deployment.  (This requires ACM certs in the same region as the API, rather than always in us-east-1.)

This gives you two different hostnames, one in each region, that you use for your DNS routing.  They look like this:

```
d-aaaaaaaaaa.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
d-bbbbbbbbbb.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

So, what next?

You use Route 53 Latency-Based routing to create a CNAME record for `api.example.com` with two targets -- one from us-east-2, one from us-west-2 -- pointing to the two respective names, along with health checks on the targets.  Route 53 will automatically resolve DNS queries to whichever regional endpoint is closer to the requester.  If, for example, you try to reach the API from us-east-1, your DNS query goes to Route 53 and there's no record there for us-east-1, so Route 53 determines that us-east-2 is the closer of the two regions, and -- assuming the us-east-2 endpoint has passed its healthcheck -- Route 53 returns the DNS record pointing to `d-aaaaaaaaaa.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`.

So, this feature creates the ability to deploy an API in multiple AWS regions that will respond to the same hostname, which is not possible with Edge Optimized API Endpoints (as all endpoints were, prior to the announcement of this new feature).

> And have CloudFront distribute the traffic for me?

Not exactly.  Or, at least, not directly.  CloudFront doesn't make origin determinations based on the requester's region, but Lambda@Edge [dynamic origin selection](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/lambda-at-edge-now-supports-content-based-dynamic-origin-selection-network-calls-from-viewer-events-and-advanced-response-generation/) could be used to modify the origin server based on the requester's general location (by evaluating which API region is nearest to the CloudFront edge that happens to be serving a specific request).

However, as you can see, above, Route 53 Latency-Based routing can do that for you.  Yet, there's still a compelling reason to put this configuration behind a CloudFront distribution, anyway... two reasons, actually...

This is in essence a DNS failover configuration, and that is notoriously unreliable when the access is being made by a browser or by a Java programmer who hasn't heard that Java seems to cache DNS lookups indefinitely.  Browsers are bad about that, too.  With CloudFront in front of your DNS failover configuration, you don't have to worry about clients caching your DNS lookup, because CloudFront does it correctly.  The TTL of your Route 53 records -- which used as an origin server behind CloudFront -- behaves as expected, so regional failover occurs correctly.

The second reason to place this configuration behind CloudFront would be if you want the traffic to be transported on the Edge Network.  If the requests are only coming from the two AWS regions where the APIs are hosted, this might not be helpful, but otherwise it should improve responsiveness overall.

---

Note that geo-redundancy across regions is not something that can be done entirely transparently with API Gateway in every scenario -- it depends on how you are using it.  One problematic case that comes to mind would involve a setup where you require IAM authentication against the incoming requests.  The `X-Amz-Credential` includes the target region, and the signature of course would differ because the signing keys in Signature V4 are based on the secret/date/region/service/signing-key paradigm (which is a brilliant design, but I digress).  This would complicate the setup since the caller would not know the target region.  There may be other complications.  Cognito may have similar complications.  But for a straightforward API where the authentication is done by your own mechanism of application tokens, cookies, etc., this new capability is very much a big deal.

Somewhat amusingly, before this new capability was announced, I was actually working on the design of a managed service that would handle failover and geo-routing of requests to redundant deployments of API Gateway across regions, including a mechanism that had the capability to compensate for the differing region required in the signature.  The future prospects of what I was working on are a bit less clear at the moment.

Comment: I'm using a distributed setup similar to what you describe above, I'm now looking to add cloudfront in front of my regional endpoints solely so that I can use waf to block abusers.

Comment: @Jonathan that sounds like a good idea.  Are you suggesting that I should include this in the answer as another reason why one might want to use CloudFront with regional endpoints in this way?

Comment: This explanation couldn't have gotten any better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It means you can deploy your API based on the region which reduces latency.

One use case would be, Say you have a Lambda function which is invoking an API request. If both Lambda and API is in the same region then you can expect high performance

Please have a look on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-regional-api.html

Comment: I think you may be missing some detail.  API Gateway has always been regional and API endpoints have always been -- ultimately -- handled the specific region where you provisioned the API.  That isn't what this changes.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your comment. Please correct me if my example is wrong, which relates to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-regional-api.html

Comment: From your link, *"When API requests predominantly originate from an EC2 instance or services within the same region as the API is deployed, a regional API endpoint will typically lower the latency of connections and is recommended for such scenarios."*  A site hosted in an S3 bucket doesn't match that scenario, because S3 wouldn't be accessing the API.

Comment: What if a Lambda invoking API? will it fit to this?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by "a Lambda invoking API."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot what I mean is to make an HTTP call (HTTP API hosted in API gateway) from Lambda function

Comment: Yes, if the Lambda function is making an HTTP request to an API Gateway endpoint in the same region, this new configuration option could trim some number of milliseconds off of the response times for the HTTP request.