# Resilient CloudFront with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

**I have edited this post to be more succinct (before someone votes it for closure on that basis.)**

I am, however, leaving the original post below, for context.

---

**New form of post:**

We currently have externally managed DNS handled (ie: we do not use Route53) and CloudFront with S3 for hosting our SPA.

We also have API Gateway (also with externally managed DNS) providing access to a mock endpoint, DynamoDB and Lambda.

The API Gateway, DynamoDB and Lambda are all hosted in the same region. (One of my S3 buckets is also in that region.)

I would like to design my architecture to reduce latency and improve fail-over as much as possible. My understanding is, in simple terms, that I should be using a design which (a) hosts each resource as close as possible to the user and (b) can fail-over to another region when the region closest to the user becomes unavailable.

My simplistic understanding, at present, is that unless I design my architecture to deploy to specific regions, the resources which are region specific (ie: api gateway, dynamodb, lambda) will become unavailable if that region becomes unavailable.

However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105589/71376) and [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) appear to say that if I want to have API Gateway deployed to multiple regions and accessible from the same URL, I must use Route53 to manage the closest-to-user addressing.

Is Route53 a requirement in this scenario?

Is single region deployment enough to ensure resilience if services which are deployed via CloudFront if that region becomes unavailable?

---

**Original post:**

**TL;DR:** I want to deploy API Gateway, Dynamo DB and Lambda with high performance and regional failure resilience. Should I rely on AWS CloudFront for as many components as possible or should I deliberately manage regional-specific deployments myself?

I am trying to make as highly available and fault resistant AWS infrastructure deployment as I can...

I have a CloudFront distribution serving S3 content from two buckets, each in a different region. I believe, for the SPA portion, this is enough to allow the SPA to provide as much speed, reliability and up time as I can (I am considering adding more origins to ensure this even further.)

I currently have an API Gateway serving requests to a DynamoDB and a Lambda (also a mock endpoint.) As these resources are deployed to the same, single region I believe this would not be failure-resistant and not provide the best response time. As illustrated in this simple diagram:

[image]

My understanding of AWS is that I have the option of deploying the API Gateway, DynamoDB and Lambda to more regions and that this will improve both the response time and reliability.

Given a service disruption in my one deployment region for API Gateway, DynamoDB and Lambda, my concerns for this deployment are:

1. For DynamoDB should I deploy to multiple regions and use [cross-region replication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/amazon-dynamodb-available-now-cross-region-replication-triggers-and-streams/) or would a [Global Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html) perform the same function? (Or are these essentially the same thing?)
2. If I deploy the API Gateway to multiple regions would I need multiple domain names?
3. [This page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) seems to imply (to me, at least) that deploying API Gateway to multiple regions with failover would require the use of Route 53 (which is not an option for me; We have naming handled externally and I have no control over this.)
4. If Edge Optimised API Gateway deployments are deployed to Edge servers, why would I consider Regional deployments when intending to improve latency, fail-over and resilience?